# A Little RegEx Help Please - Part 2

Tags: java, regex

Here's the input string:

```
loadMedia('mediacontainer1', 'http://www.something.com/videos/JohnsAwesomeVideo.flv', 'http://www.something.com/videos/JohnsAwesomeCaption.xml', '/videos/video-splash-image.gif')
```

With this RegExp: **(?<=')[^']+.xml(?=')**

... we get this:

```
http://www.something.com/videos/JohnsAwesomeCaption.xml
```

... which is exactly what I wanted. BUT this time I'd like to select the complete string EXCEPT for the above. Basically an inverse selection. The output should look like this:

```
loadMedia('mediacontainer1', 'http://www.something.com/videos/JohnsAwesomeVideo.flv', '', '/videos/video-splash-image.gif')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which language you are using but in **Java** you can do:

```
str = "loadMedia('mediacontainer1', 'http://www.something.com/videos/JohnsAwesomeVideo.flv', 'http://www.something.com/videos/JohnsAwesomeCaption.xml', '/videos/video-splash-image.gif')";
System.out.println(str.replaceFirst("(?<=')[^']+\\.xml(?=')", ""));
```

Or in **php** use this code:

```
$str = "loadMedia('mediacontainer1', 'http://www.something.com/videos/JohnsAwesomeVideo.flv', 'http://www.something.com/videos/JohnsAwesomeCaption.xml', '/videos/video-splash-image.gif')";
echo preg_replace("~(?<=')[^']+\.xml(?=')~", "", $str);
```

#### OUTPUT (from both)

```
loadMedia('mediacontainer1', 'http://www.something.com/videos/JohnsAwesomeVideo.flv', '', '/videos/video-splash-image.gif')
```

### EDIT

Use following Java code to break the string into 2 parts as per your comments:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*)(?<=')[^']+\\.xml(?=')(.*)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find())
   System.out.println("Output: " + m.group(1) + "<br /><br />" + m.group(2));
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Matched: loadMedia('mediacontainer1', 'http://www.something.com/videos/JohnsAwesomeVideo.flv', '<br /><br />', '/videos/video-splash-image.gif')
```

Comment: Your Java solution works. However, how can I split the output into two parts? For instance: <br /><br />`$1 = loadMedia('mediacontainer1', 'http://www.something.com/videos/JohnsAwesomeVideo.flv', ''` <br /><br /> `$2 = ', '/videos/video-splash-image.gif')`

Comment: Sure it can be done, please see **EDIT** section above. Hope that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 5):

Do a match of your pattern, get the substring that matched, then do a replace of that exact substring with an empty string (or '', or whatever). If your language has the option to return the indices that matched rather than the text that matched it's even easier because you can just remove the text range identified by the indices.

Some languages provide a "regusb" (regular expression substitute) command that lets you replace a regular expression with another string, which lets you do the match-and-replace all in one step. Different languages may call that command by different names.

Comment: +1 good point to show a way without regex (or reusing result from prev regex)

Answer (score 3):

Try this if you have to do the task in Regex:
Replace

```
(.+)(?<=')[^']+\.xml(?=')(.+)
```

with

```
$1$2
```